# BlackBerry: Getting click on manager and button field simultanously

Tags: layout, blackberry

I have an verticalFieldManager  as shown in fig. and in this manager I have some label field and a button field.
Now on the click of the manager I have to go to other screen and on the click of that arrow button I have to show the details.
Please give me some idea how can I do that.

[image: fig.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) consume the click event. The simple way to do this is with a style bit passed to the constructor: ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK

Answer (score 0):

1. First add a HorizontalFieldManager.
2. Then add VerticalFieldManager and button(to show detail) to this HorizontalFieldManager.
3. Now add seperate Listener to both HorizontalFieldManager(to goto next  screen) and the button(to show detail).

Comment: i done that but when when you clicked on button its navigation clicked will called and after that managers navigation click will called. It doesn't work at all